# Parse html document with NekoHTML

Tags: java, html, parsing, cyberneko

I am using NekoHTML framework with xerces 2.11.0 version to parse an HTML document.
But i am having a problem with this simple code :

```
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
System.out.println(parser.getClass().toString());
InputSource url = new InputSource("http://www.cbgarden.org");
try{
    parser.parse(url);
    Document document = parser.getDocument();
    System.out.println(document.hasChildNodes());
    System.out.println(document.getBaseURI());
    System.out.println(document.getNodeName());
    System.out.println(document.getNodeValue());
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I put here the result of the multiple prints:

1. class org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMParser
2. true
3. http://www.cbgarden.org
4. document
5. null

So my question is : What could be wrong ?
No exception is thrown and I am following the rules that are defined in the usage rules in the NekoHTML. My build path libraries are with this precedence:

1. nekohtml.jar
2. nekohtmlSamples.jar
3. xercesImpl.jar
4. xercesSamples.jar
5. xml-apis.jar

Comment: I just have one more question regarding this subject :
Why the method parser.getDocument() returns one document with two nodes, in which one of them is NULL ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is about the `null`?
The *document* node has no value. It only has subnodes (like `<html>` witch contains `<head>` and `<body>`).

But if you want to have the whole page source as a String, you can simply download it using a `URL` its method `openStream()`.

Comment: Yeah i am seeing this know.If i make document.getChildNodes() , the result will be two nodes, one of them return "HTML" if i use getLocalName() and the other returs NULL.How i see all the document , if i use document.toString it returns [document: null]